# Print an array in Twig

Tags: php, css, arrays, twig, silex

I Have a table with this columns:

```
login ,couleur1,parties,gagnees
```

I would like to print an array exactly like this one:

> [image]

In Silex I get all data in an array

```
$app->get('/userlist', function(Application $app) {

$recup= $app['db']->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM users');
$results = $recup->fetchAll();

return $app['twig']->render('example.twig', array('users' => $results));
});

$app->run();
[enter image description here][2]?>
```

In Twig I tried to align them, but I can't get it like in the photo.

```
 {% for row in users %}
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
        <li style="float:left; margin-right:30px" >{{ row.login }}</li>
        <li style="float:left; margin-right:30px">{{row.parties}}</li>
        <li style="float:left; margin-right:30px">{{row.couleur1}}</li>
        <li style="float:both">{{row.couleur2}}</li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

I would make that without separating CSS and Twig.

Comment: you should look into using a `<table>` for this.

Comment: It's legit tabular data. Just use a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Joueur</td>
    <td>Parties</td>
    <td>Gagness</td>
    <td>Colueur Preferee</td>
  </tr>
  {% for row in users %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row.login }}</td>
        <td>{{row.parties}}</td>
        <td>{{row.couleur1}}</td>
        <td>{{row.couleur2}}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}

</table>
```

and apply some CSS for colors and looks.